# Facebook feed dialog - how to put status automatically

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed, status

I have used the javascript code for developing facebook feed dialog and its working perfectly.

But I also want to fill the "Say something here.." field automatically, which appear on popup.

I m not sure how to do it. I have checked the facebook feed dialog documentation for that but have not find anything relevant yet.

Anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

- Filling in the messages field is not possible (anymore), at least not
  with the JavaScript SDK. Any message parameter will just be ignored.
- The message field must always be filled with
  user 100% generated content if you use the PHP SDK (see Facebook terms).

> https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ (see IV.2)

Remember, it´s a "personal message", not something you would/should create with an app.

Answer (score 0):

you are violating the facebook policy by automatically prefilling the message field.
•You should check this link.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill